# Measure Page Load Time Speed in Single Page Applications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, vue.js, single-page-application

I researched a lot on how to measure the page load times in a single page application like React, Vue etc but did not get any proper answer.

- In Websites that are built using Single Page Application frameworks/libraries like vue, react etc load the initial page only once and then all the route changes do not fire a page load. To understand it better let us say our landing page is **/index**. When index route is loaded it is considered a Page Load but when we change the route to let's say **/index/products** here SPA takes care of it and loads the content using **AJAX** without loading the page.
- But in websites that are built **without** SPA frameworks the case is different it loads every page on route changes and we can run the below line of code on each page and get the performance metrics.

  ```
  performance.getEntriesByName(window.location.href)
  ```

This line of code simply returns a dataset containing some information about the page load speeds as shown in the image below.
[image]

So in SPA it runs only once and not when we change the routes. So what I want to do here is that I need to make this line run on every route change so that I get the above performance metrics that are shown in the image for every page.

Right now it only runs for the main page and when I change the routes inside the website, it does not run for every page. But in the case of reload it works properly because reload is again a new page load.

Comment: Good question, I solved the same problem using Puppeteer tracing. But it is just a simulation of end-user metrics. If you need end-user metrics, you will probably implement custom metrics.

Comment: @AhmetCanGüven But the issue here is that i cant use puppeteer to do that because i want to capture the metrics for different users, as how the page is loading for each one of them.

Comment: After the initial page load all further SPA page navigations will only trigger additional XHR requests, which don't count as normal page loads. You could maybe programatically count how long certain requests take from inside Router navigation guards

Comment: @leuquim Yeah what you're saying is correct i can also use `performance.now()` when requests start and end to calculate the time taken. but as you can see i have attached the image for reference those values are only provided by the performance API. So the thing is that how can i use performance api in this case.